# Dynamic Render in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a "view" page in Yii.
It is cached with page cache.
Now, I want to insert some dynamic content:

```
$this->renderDynamic('renderPartial','view_name');
```

The rendered view looks like this:

```
<?php some code ?>  
<div>...some html...</div>
```

The code works fine, but there is this error:

> <###dynamic-0###>

So I understand the html is being echoed instead of returned.
I try to pass the return=true to the renderPartial function.
What is the right syntax to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More info: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderDynamic-detail

1. Cached view file:

   ```
   $this->renderDynamic('dynamicTest');
   ```
2. Controller file (callback function):

   ```
   public function dynamicTest()
   {
       return $this->renderPartial('dynamicTest', null, true);
   }
   ```
3. Dynamic view file:

   ```
   echo 'dynamicTest_' . time();
   ```

I think that You forgot to add return in callback function (step 2).

Answer (score 3):

> I try to pass the return=true to the renderPartial function. What is
>   the right syntax to do it?

[third param of renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) is needed flag

```
   $this->renderDynamic('renderPartial','view_name', null, true);
```